# Problem to create directory in Android

Tags: android, mkdirs

I'm developing a simple application for Android devices.

I need to create a directory, but I can't do it.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ()+"/dir");

if(folder.mkdirs()){
   CrearToast("Directorio creado"); //successfully created
}else{
   CrearToast("fallo"); // error creating directory
}
```

*CrearToast creates a toast with the text in brackets.

I have set 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: Are you sure the directory is not already created, it sounds like http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs() will return false if they did not need to make the dirs directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you trying to write on SD card or phone memory??
Have you looked at this??
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

EDIT:
This is how i create my folders

```
File CheckDirectory;
CheckDirectory = new File(FolderPath);
if (!CheckDirectory.exists()){ 
CheckDirectory.mkdir();
}
```

`SD card directory`:

> `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";`

Comment: I'm trying to write on SD card. I can list every file on SD but cannot create a directory

Comment: I've checked with the link you sent me and SD card is readable and writable.